# How to enable git-crypt in heroku deploy?

Tags: heroku, deployment, web-deployment, heroku-cli, git-crypt

I am changing my deploy from AWS to heroku, my back-end application is built with the Node-Hapi-MongoDb(mLab) stack.
However, I want to hide my environment variables (i.e: MongoDb URL, Token, JsonWebToken Secret etc etc...). So I have implemented git-crypt successfully within github and AWS. It worked fine. But I had to manually decrypt in the AWS server.

So when I try to deploy to the Heroku with the command:

```
git push heroku master
```

I can see the files encrypted by the git-crypt does not get decrypted.

I have tried to follow this README [heroku-buildpack-git-crypt](https://github.com/jotes/heroku-buildpack-git-crypt)

But i could not understand a few things:

1. *ou have to create a gpg key for your heroku app: gpg --default-new-key-algo rsa4096 --gen-key*

***Always that I try to create a gpg-key with this command I receive the following message:***

```
Note that this key cannot be used for encryption.  You may want to use
the command "--edit-key" to generate a subkey for this purpose.
```

2. *Then, you have to add this key to your repository to make it a contributor:* 
   `git crypt add-gpg-user <email of your key for your heroku app>`

My repository already had git-crypt but with a different email than the one i am using in heroku, does the email has to be the same?

3. *After that, you have to specify GPG_PRIVATE_KEY in Heroku with contents of the private key.*

***What is the GPG_PRIVATE_KEY in Heroku with contents and how can i get this information?***

***My question is: how can i configure the git-crypt with heroku?***
or

***Is there an automated way of deploying an encrypted github repo to the heroku and inside heroku environment decrypt and run the application?***

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get this working?

Comment: No friend and I don't use this technology anymore.